# simulate '0' keypress in flash using javascript

Tags: jquery, flash, keypress, oracle-adf

trying to simulate '0' press using javascript on a flash embed element, 
like it involves a button click inside flash, but there is alternative for button press 
ie keypress '0' ,
I would like to run this javascript at the load,
For this i should invoke programmatic '0' press.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simulate keypress. But you can pretend :)

If on keypress '0' your program execute some code, exec this code on flash element startup directly...

Comment: hmm i dont have the access to the code, it is internally written in AS, all i was using is a swf file, i dont have the source of it.

Comment: http://www.flash-decompiler.com/   Examine code and if you are lucky you find the function. Than call them with JS ( document.getElementById("flash_object").movieclip1.movieclip2.functionName() or something similar )